# .mode ascii throws error on sqlite3

Tags: sqlite, ubuntu-14.04, ascii

1. I cannot switch to ascii mode on sqlite3.
2. I used .help to check the kind of modes we can switch to, but i found       that the ascii package is missing.
3. How do i fix it?
   [image: screenshot of .mode ascii]

[image: screenshot of .help "ascii is missing in the instructions"]

Answer (score 0):

There is no "ascii package".

You have to update to an SQLite version that is recent enough to have this feature. "Ubuntu 14.4" doesn't sound like that.